# What is LongWritable key input for the map()?

Tags: mapreduce

I have 2 text files of 1 MB each stored in HDFS as inputs to my MapReduce program. In the following line, we consider the input pair  for the map() is .

```
class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
```

What is LongWritable key here? How is it assumed by the MapReduce? Does each line of text in the input file has a key or a single key is assumed for complete text in the file (i.e, all the lines at a time)?

Answer (score 9):

1- The LongWritable key here is the `offset` of the line which means `position` of that line in the file and `not` the line number. There is `a lot` of difference between these 2.

2- It is `not assumed` by MapReduce framework. It is the duty of the `InputFormat` you are using  in you MR job to decide it. Default is `TextInputFormat` which gives byte offset of the line as the key, as in your case.

3- Well, it again depends on your InputFormat. If you are using TextInputFormat then each line will be treated as the value with its offset as the key. But you could have your own custom InputFormat which may give you just one key for the whole file and all the lines of that file altogether as the value.

Comment: position is clearly not the number. may i have the reason for the downvote?IMHO, it's the correct definition, based on what i have learnt about mapreduce. also, could you please point me to the documentation you are referring to. i would really appreciate that. thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It is byte offset of line or you can say line number

Comment: you should have skipped the 'or' part of your answer. offset is not the line no. it's the byte position of the line.

Comment: I am not getting this. How come offset of a line is same as the number of that line?I would request you to help me in understanding this.